# Написание слов-терминов с и без кавычек

Tags: правописание

Как правильно использовать кавычки при написании терминов и их определений на сайтах, которые используются в интерфейсе пользователя?

То есть вводится термин, который обозначает некое действие. К этому действие добавляется всплывающая подсказка, которое его описывает. Требуется ли в этом случае использование кавычек?

Яркий пример "тревога" на данном сайте. Следует ли использовать кавычки при написании и определение действия? Если да, на сколько это критично?

> сообщение, отмеченное «тревогой»

Или

> сообщение, отмеченное тревогой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так: сообщение, отмеченное знаком «тревога».

Или: сообщение, отмеченное знаком  тревоги.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь надо ориентироваться на общие правила. Т.к. еще не разработаны правила, регламентирующие употребление кавычек с названиями интернет-терминов. Придется ориентироваться на уже существующие правила. Согласно правилу '' Употребление кавычек'', в одном из пунктов сказано: ''слова, представляющие собой малоизвестные термины, берутся в кавычки''. Поскольку термин ''тревога'' малоизвестный, кавычки нужны, чтобы показать, что это именно название функции.

P.S.Что такое "провал перевода''?

Answer (score 1):

В данном примере кавычки нужны для обозначения условного характера употребления этого слова (будь это широко употребляемый термин или только что оговоренный), иначе выражение можно понять не формально, а буквально ("по содержанию сообщение было тревожного характера").  Основная проблема - в двусмысленности, от неясности, термин ли это. Без кавычек можно обойтись, предварив такой термин пояснительным словом (символ тревоги).

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно писать кавычки, то это провал перевода, и надо переформулировать. Если нет полноценного слова, и изобрели свою терминологию, то не надо стыдиться её и бояться писать без кавычек.

Осмысленности изобретённом термину кавычки не добавят, а вот путаницу создадут: кавычки ещё и для обозначения переносного смысла используются. И потом поди разберись — то ли "тревога", то ли "тревога наоборот", особенно если слово употребляется и с кавычками, и без.

Я уж не говорю про то, что чистоты интерфейсу кавычки никак не добавят.

Моё мнение: лучше не изобретать новые слова, а потом стыдливо прятать их за кавычками, а просто использовать общепринятые слова "жалоба" и "пожаловаться", которые понятны всем без объяснений, и не заморачиваться, что слово "слишком негативное".